# Postgres SQL array aggregate values from a single table based on conditions

Tags: postgresql

I'm a SQL newbie and I'm trying to write the following query:

I have the following table:

```
 user_id | chat_id 
---------+---------
```

Which represents a many to many mapping of users to chat rooms;

I'm looking to create a query that finds all the `chat_id`s that are associated with the input `user_id`, and then array aggregates all the `user_id`s associated with those chats excluding the input `user_id`.

So the result should look like this for example:

```
 chat_id | user_id 
---------+---------
    1     {1,3,5,6}
```

I've kind of jumbled together to following query; but I'm pretty sure I got something wrong:

```sql
WITH chatIDs AS (SELECT user_chats.chat_id FROM user_chats WHERE user_chats.user_id=$1)
WITH userIDs AS (SELECT user_chats.user_id FROM user_chats WHERE user_chats.chat_id=chatIDs AND user_chats.user_id != $1)
SELECT chatIDs, array_agg(userIDs) FROM user_chats;
```

EDIT:

Edited for clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you could just use a where clause to exclude the user:

```
SELECT chat_id, array_agg(user_id) FROM user_chats
WHERE user_id != $1 AND chat_id IN (SELECT chat_id FROM user_chats WHERE user_id = $1)
GROUP BY chat_id
```

Comment: This makes sense! But I first have to find all the `chat_id`s that are associated with the input `user_id`, and then array aggregate all the `user_id`s associated with those chats, but I think your query definetly comes close

Comment: @AdrianCoutsoftides I see, if I understand you correctly you can achieve that by adding another condition (see the edited answer)

Comment: you beautiful person!